# Ignoring newlines in embedded ruby in haml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I have a long piece of embedded ruby that I don't want to put on one line. It's far from done, but it starts like this:

```
.office-img{:style => "background-image: url(#{image_path "http://placehold.it/219x250&text=Office"}",
            "data-lease-type" => office_listing.office_type)}
```

Is there a way to make it so I can break to new lines to organize my code without haml throwing me errors about indentation and such?

Comment: have you tried '\' at the end of the line (without the quotes)? I'm not sure if that would allow you to break indentation though.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [section of the documentation for using more than one line](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#multiline).

In the case of element attributes like this you can spread them over multiple lines as long as each newline is directly after a comma (the example you give is slightly wrong which might be giving you a spurious error – check your parentheses):

```haml
.office-img{:style => "background-image: url(#{image_path "http://placehold.it/219x250&text=Office"})",
            "data-lease-type" => office_listing.office_type}
```